# Vertical align not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have this simple markup and css for vertically align a box

It's working fine and as expected in FF, but it isn't on Chrome. Any ideas on why is this happening and how to solve it?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 25px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#box
{
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/5fLr00tf/

Firefox output:

[image: FIREFOX (desired)]

Chrome ouput:

[image: Chrome (not desired)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add `position: absolute;` for the `#box`, also you forgot to give `left: 12.5%;`, which is needed for horizontal centering:

```css
#box {
    height: 150px;
    margin: -75px auto 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 12.5%;
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ya0ewky/**

Comment: I think you got it. I was asuming that firefox was doing it right.

Comment: The left 12.5% is the halft of the remaining 25% of available horizontal space, right?

Comment: @Matías yes, you are right. Half of the available horizontal space. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I think Chrome is actually correct. Since the #box is positioned relative, the top property has no effect. If you need to keep it relatively positioned you could adjust its position with the margin-top property. Otherwise use absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is ok. It doesn't take into account this rule: `top: 50%`. `top` cannot be declared in percentages if you have haven't set height to parent and your child item has `position: relative`.

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5fLr00tf/2/) with only added height to parent. It works as expected

Comment: You really don't need to limit the height of the parent. That's the main thing.

Comment: @1l13v I didn't specify that, but I agree with Praveen...There's no need to limit the parent's height

Comment: Ok if that's your constraint. But usually when you use percentages you have to take into account that you have set the parent's height. And I think it would be nice to mention that into your question.

Comment: @1l13v LoL. Delete your comment. Not your answer. Your answer is good, voted up too! `:P`